# IF/THEN statement for text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my Excel spreadsheet:-

- In Cells A1 and down I have cities listed. For instance Cell A1 has: "Daytona Beach, FL"
- In Cells B1 and down I have some generic information with the word CITY in it.
  For instance: Cell B1 has "Compare mortgage & refinance rates from different mortgage lenders and brokers in CITY. Find the home refinance rate you were looking for in CITY."

Is there a formula to replace the word CITY that is in the contents of Cell B1 with the contents of Cell A1?

Answer (score 1):

In a third cell

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"CITY",A1)
```